# pivot data frame in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
people1 trait1 YES
people1 trait2 YES
people1 trait3 NO
people1 trait4 RED
people2 trait1 NO
people2 trait2 YES
people2 trait4 BLACK
```

etc..

It's possible to create from that table something like this?

```
        trait1, trait2, trait3, trait4 ...
people1  YES     YES     NO      RED
people2  NO      YES     -       BLACK
people3  -        -      YES     BLUE
```

The file is too big to do that in excel, I tried in pandas, but I can't find help in this case.
I found pd.pivot_table funcion but I can't build working code. I tried and got various erors (99% my fault).

Can someone explain me how to use it in my case? Or maybe is better option than pandas.pivot?+

**EDIT**

```
I rebuild my frame:
1      'interpretation'     'trait'
p1           YES               t1
p1           BLACK             t2
p1           NO                t3
p2           NO                t1
p2           RED               t2
p2           NO                t3
```

And I use suggestion:

data1.pivot_table(index=1, columns="name", values='trait', aggfunc=','.join, fill_value='-').

And I got:

```
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found
```

If I change

data1.pivot_table(index=1, columns="trait", values='value', aggfunc=','.join, fill_value='-').

I got bad order table but without error:

```
     p1      p2    p3    p4
YES  trait1  t1
YES  t1      t2 etc.
NO
RED
No
...
```

So i think, the first option is correct, but I cant repair that error. When I dtype df it return (O) for all cols.

Comment: Can you add your code, errors?

Comment: usually : ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
even I drop duplicates from df. I think I just do something wrong logical.
And I saw that post that u marked, but I can resolve my problem based on it.

Comment: Now my code looks that: `data1.pivot(index=1, columns=2, values=3).drop_duplicates()` I mean that pivot part, but I still keep trying, and that is simplest verion. I try do anything with it.

Comment: I suggest use `df = df.pivot_table(index='col1', columns='col2', values='col3', aggfunc=','.join, fill_value='-')`

Comment: Thank U for answer. It's creating table. It's totally different that what I need but as  I understand that I'm mismatching the columns to the arguments. I'll try.

Comment: @jezrael Can u look on my EDIT? Coz I don't want to write a new post but that is locked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem is missing values in column `trait`, so `join` function failed. So possible solution is replace missing values to empty strings:

```
print (data1)
    1   name trait
0  p1    YES   NaN <- missing value
1  p1  BLACK    t2
2  p1     NO    t3
3  p2     NO    t1
4  p2    RED    t2
5  p2     NO    t3

data1['trait'] = data1['trait'].fillna('')
df = data1.pivot_table(index=1, 
                       columns="name", 
                       values='trait', 
                       aggfunc=','.join, 
                       fill_value='-')
print (df)
1      p1     p2
name            
BLACK  t2      -
NO     t3  t1,t3
RED     -     t2
YES            -
```

Also if want convert index to column:

```
data1['trait'] = data1['trait'].fillna('')
df = (data1.pivot_table(index=1, 
                       columns="name", 
                       values='trait', 
                       aggfunc=','.join, 
                       fill_value='-')
           .reset_index()
           .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
print (df)
    name  p1     p2
0  BLACK  t2      -
1     NO  t3  t1,t3
2    RED   -     t2
3    YES          -
```